# Splash window doesn't close - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, splash-screen, expression-blend

I have a splash screen with a progress bar, and once it is loaded completely the main window should open. However the main window doesn't open at all, and the splash window remains even after the progress bar is fully loaded. What is wrong?

In App.xaml, I have set StartupUri="SplashWindow.xaml"

**Splash Window Code:**

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace Project_1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SplashWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SplashWindow : Window
{
    public SplashWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


       Duration duration = new Duration(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
       DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new     DoubleAnimation(splash_load.Maximum, duration);
       splash_load.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation); 

        if (splash_load.Value==100) //If progress bar (Name = "splash_load") loads completely
        {

        // Close splash window
        this.Close();

        // Open main window
        var mw = new revised_mainwindow();
        mw.Show();

        }

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: You can't close something thats not even been shown yet, I've not used WPF in a while but I'm sure it had an onshown event or similar?

Comment: your logic seems incorrect  please try this  link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026209/wpf-splashscreen-with-progressbar for another example

Comment: @TommyGrovnes: I tried it, but I am getting issues with DispatchPriority.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF showing dialog before main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539958/wpf-showing-dialog-before-main-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your logic.

When the `if` statement executes at that time `splash_load.Value` is not 100, because the animation is started but not finished till this point. Some how you will have to check this condition after completing the animation. Use `Completed` event of `Animation` to check for the condition and show your Main Window.

Comment: I attached an event handler for the Completed event of double Animation. It worked. Thank you!