# Splashscreen does not show

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a `SplashScreen` in the following way:

1. Created a new window with some controls such as an undeterminated progressbar for display the loading and a label
2. Added this code to the splashscreen window:

`ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="Blue" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="AliceBlue"`

then in my `App.xaml.cs` I wrote this in the OnStartup:

```
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();  
splash.Show();  

MainWindow main = new MainWindow();   

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)  
{  
    Thread.Sleep(i);  
}  

splash.Close();  

main.Show();
```

now the problem's that the splashscreen does not show, seems the app is busy or something similar, why?

UPDATE:

I wrote this code as suggested:

```
private void _applicationInitialize(Views.SplashScreen splashWindow)
    {
        var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

        //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Invoker)delegate
        //{
        //    MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        //    MainWindow.Show();
        //});
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Show();
    }
```

but the mainwindow doesn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `Thread.Sleep` method causes the UI thread to sleep until the loop is done. Its better to use the `DispatcherTimer` for this sort of thing, which will spin up a background thread.

When the `Tick` event on the `DispatcherTimer` is raised, you can close the splash screen window then.

See the following link for an example of its usage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

**EDIT**

In your edited code in the question, I realized the `DispatcherTimer` variable is a method-scoped variable when it should be a class-level scoped variable. The below is half psuedo-code, but should guide in how to setup the behavior:

```
public class Program
{
    // This is a very rough snippet of the application startup piece. Its psuedo-code.
    public void Main()
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        App.Run(mainWindow);
    }
}

public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    private Window splashWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.splashWindow = new SplashWindow();
        this.splashWindow.Show();

        this.dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.splashWindow.Close();
        this.mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, the idea is to have the main window to control the display of the splash window. So I have the main window create an instance of the splash window, then use the `DispatcherTimer` to manage when to close it, and finally show the main window itself.

Comment: so I should add the splash on the dispatcher?

Comment: You will want to simply run the `main.Show()` in the dispatcher timer's tick event.

Comment: I added this `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Invoker)delegate
            {
                MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                MainWindow.Show();
            });` now the splash screen appear but I saw some lags, how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you still have that for-loop in your code? That should be removed if its still there.

Comment: Instead of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`, use the `DispatcherTimer` object as the example in the link I proved does.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Thread.Sleep and your splash screen is on same thread, you wont be able to see it. Possible duplicate of [WPF SplashScreen with ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026209/wpf-splashscreen-with-progressbar)